# Synchronize database columns in 2 tables in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, triggers

We have columns in 2 tables the values for which need to be the same.

```
Table 1
ID | ColumnA

Table 2
ID | ColumnB
```

We have this redundancy to support an existing application. Once a migration happens ColumnB in Table 2 will not be used anymore.  However, until this happens, the 2 columns will need to be in sync. I had suggested a trigger to accomplish this and drop the trigger once the migration is complete.

I was told this is not usually done and should be done in application code. Why is a trigger not a good option?

Comment: Are all the modifictions happening on `ColumnA`?  Or are there changes happening on both columns which would mean that you needed bidirectional synchronization?

Comment: Most likely scenario is uni-directional update on ColumnA only but cannot rule out a bi-directional case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger is pretty much safe; everything stays in the database which takes care about it. There's no "back door", i.e. you have two "forms" in that application and modified one to perform synchronization, but *forgot* to do the same in another and here you are, out of sync.

Drawback for the trigger option is that it fires for each row affected. If you're doing it on a single row, or even a few hundreds of rows, everything will be fine. However, if vast millions of rows are involved, then you can expect things to slow down because ... well, trigger fires for each of them, a million times.

However, the way you described it ("should be done in application code"), I guess that it shouldn't be an issue, looks like it is more like row-by-row processing. Though, I might be wrong.